# Render list from markdown frontmatter variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a list in markdown frontmatter like so:

```
---
tags:
 - one
 - two
 - three
---
my content
```

Same problem like when I have this in my .md:

```
tags: one, two, three, four, five
```

In my vue app layout I have this:

```
<ul>
<li>{{ tags }}</li>
</ul>
```

This shows all tags in array like so:

```
["one", "two"]
```

I tried this:

```
    <ul>
     <li v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag">{{ tag }}</li>
    </ul>
```

That did not work... How to fix for nice list ordered showing for both scenarios (in list with dash, and in list with comma separated)?

I use JS-YAML... https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml

Comment: What are you using to process the markdown frontmatter?

Comment: That's relevant to the answer :) I've added [tag:nuxt.js] to your post.

Comment: @tony19 - its this... https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml - JS-YAML

Comment: You said you were using Nuxt earlier...